# Firebase phone authentication accessToken

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I have been using **Firebase Phone Authentication** for my **Expo react-native** project and now I am trying to access authenticated user data like phone no from **access-token**.

Can anyone please suggest me how to access user object from the **access-token** returned by

```
firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
```

Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please reference to these links:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signinwithcredential

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#usercredential

Example:

```
const user = await firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
console.log(user.additionalUserInfo);
```

Comment: First of thank you for your response. From the above function I can surely get the user data but my question is, Is there any way through which just by using the returned access-token can I get data of the authenticated user.

Comment: I'm not sure what is your `access-token`. If it is in the JWT format, you can use https://jwt.io/ to decode it to find out. JWT is construct of header / payload / signature. The "data" you looking for may be in the payload.

Comment: firebase.auth().currentUser returns the object contaning following - "stsTokenManager": Object {
    "accessToken": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjIzNzA1ZmNmY-K5VwLm1I5gfPERppLmU9lAA9mCqdfvjWg4cfVTkCbb2js1nsahIRewcg....",
    "apiKey": "<API-KEY>",
    "expirationTime": 1602244796855,
    "refreshToken": "AG8BCndyzFUyC73IkxQl5VsqvAuLnmBPX39IyBkaqr7EWkePJTTCQZNtiR0rtaKeEbBnpD3PiYPnf7Ak35pEccHWEHCFiIiNCuHL-JWKngLny-bv-P....",
  },